# how to declare dynamic variables in python with a test

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic, variable-assignment

I know its possible to declare dynamic variables using this method :

```
for x in range(0, 7):
    globals()[f"variable1{x}"] = x
```

What i want to do is something like :

```
ls = [1,31,42,56, ...]
for x in range(0, len(ls)):
    globals()[f"variable{x}"] = 10*x if ls[x] %2 == 0 else globals()[f"variable{x}"] = 11*x
```

Code is random beacause i tried to make it as simple as possible, apologies.

What i am actually trying to do is :

```
for i in range(0,4):
       globals()[f"numb{i}"] = tk.Label(root, text=(best[i] +"\n"+dates[0]),width=10,height=3, bg="#F4F5B7") if len(best) >= i else tk.Label(root, text=('UNDEFINED'),width=10,height=3, bg="#F4F5B7")
numb[i].grid(row=1,column=(i+5))
```

Where `best[]` is user inputed

Comment: The syntax would be  globals()[f"variable{x}"] = 10*x if ls[x] %2 == 0 else 11*x
You do not need to repeat the "globals()[f"variable{x}"] = " in a if else expression.

Answer (score 1):

You try to assign the value in the if and the else.
The "x if condition else y" is by itself a value so you can assign it to something you don't have to assign in the if and else part. So you should use :

```
ls = [1,31,42,56, ...]
for x in range(0, len(ls)):
    globals()[f"variable{x}"] = 10*x if ls[x] % 2 == 0 else 11*x
```

Please also note that in 9 out of 10 cases, dynamic variable allocation is a bad practice, in most situation it can be replaced with a dictionary like :

```
ls = [1,31,42,56, ...]
values = {}
for x in range(0, len(ls)):
    values[f"variable{x}"] = 10*x if ls[x] % 2 == 0 else 11*x

#Then later access the values this way
print(values["variable31"]) #print whatever is 11**31
```

Comment: i know but the thing is that i am trying to set tkinter labels, wich i guess are not 'values' per say

Comment: No they are values it is perfectly fine to do `values["numb2"] = tk.Label(root, text=(best[2] +"\n"+dates[0]),width=10,height=3, bg="#F4F5B7") if len(best) >= 2 else tk.Label(root, text=('UNDEFINED'),width=10,height=3, bg="#F4F5B7") ` then later to use `values["numb2"].grid(row=1,column=(i+5))`